# how do i make the sql query work faster

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
select * from student@LINK1 
where id in(select id from classs@LINK1 where a_id in 
             (select id from desk@LINK1 where USN in (1,2,3,4,5,6)))
               and id not in 
                 (select id from student where id in 
                   (select id from classs where a_id in 
                     (select id from desk where USN in (1,2,3,4,5,6))));
```

The above query take 15 minutes to fetch the data.
can any one help me how do make it work faster

Comment: How many rows in `select id from student where id in 
                   (select id from classs where a_id in 
                     (select id from desk where USN in (1,2,3,4,5,6))`?

Comment: There are 189883 rows

Comment: and on LINK how many rows? (`select id from classs@LINK1 where a_id in 
             (select id from desk@LINK1 where USN in (1,2,3,4,5,6))`)?

Comment: Do you have indexes on all columns you use in `where` clauses? Also, it might be a little faster with `left join`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having 200k rows to compare you must make sure you don't do nested loops:

```
select /*+use_hash(remot local)*/
    remot.*
from (
     select * from student@LINK1 
     where id in(select id from classs@LINK1 where a_id in 
                   (select id from desk@LINK1 where USN in (1,2,3,4,5,6)))
     ) remot
left join
      (select id from student where id in 
             (select id from classs where a_id in 
                     (select id from desk where USN in (1,2,3,4,5,6)))
      ) local
on local.id = remot.id
where local.id is null;
```

EDIT: After reading the comments, I think it may worth to rewrite the query:

```
select * 
from student@LINK1 
where id in 
   (
     select id 
     from classs@LINK1 
     where a_id in 
              (select id from desk@LINK1 where USN in (1,2,3,4,5,6))
           and id not in
                    (select id from classs where a_id in 
                       (select id from desk where USN in (1,2,3,4,5,6))
    )
;
```

Because it will surpass some joins. The `not in` in This query may be also rewritten as `left join`.

Comment: This is taking even more time

Comment: How much time is taking the remote query? I mean: `select * from student@LINK1 
     where id in(select id from classs@LINK1 where a_id in 
                   (select id from desk@LINK1 where USN in (1,2,3,4,5,6)))`

Comment: So, you won't get it to work faster than 5 min. How many rows you get?

Comment: 189803 rows rows i got

Comment: Thank you so much for spending time in helping me.